# Populate dataTable with knockout observable array

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js, datatables

I want to populate my dataTable with knockoutjs objervable array.
here is my javascript code:

```
function AppViewModel()
{
var self = this;
self.tableData = ko.observableArray();

 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "<?php echo $this->config->base_url('api/categoryList')?>",    
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            self.tableData(result);
        },

    error: function (err) {
            alert("err");
        }
      });// you have missed this bracket

}

var vm = new AppViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

here is my HTML:

The json objest that I am getting from ajax request is:

```
{
    "aaData": [
        {
            "client_Id": "",
            "categoryId": "1",
            "categoryName": "Individual",
            "categoryDescription": "",
            "lastUpdatedBy": ""
        },
        {
            "client_Id": "",
            "categoryId": "2",
            "categoryName": "Firm",
            "categoryDescription": "",
            "lastUpdatedBy": ""
        },
        {
            "client_Id": "",
            "categoryId": "3",
            "categoryName": "Private Limited Company",
            "categoryDescription": "",
            "lastUpdatedBy": ""
        },
        {
            "client_Id": "",
            "categoryId": "5",
            "categoryName": "company",
            "categoryDescription": "",
            "lastUpdatedBy": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I am getting object is not a function error in javascript and DataTable cannot be reinitialize alert.

```
<table class="table table-bordered" 
    data-bind="
        dataTable: { 
            aaData: tableData, 
            options: { 
                        bJQueryUI: true, 
                        aoColumns: [ 
                            { sTitle: 'categoryName', mData: 'categoryName' }, 
                            { sTitle: 'categoryDescription', mData: 'categoryDescription' } 
                        ] 
                    } 
        }" 
/>
```

Please help with this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are populating the `observableArray` with a object that is not an array:

```
success: function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    self.tableData(result);
```

and you say that

```
result = {
    "aaData": [
        {"client_Id":"","categoryId":"1","categoryName":"Individual","categoryDescription":"","lastUpdatedBy":""},
        {"client_Id":"","categoryId":"2","categoryName":"Firm","categoryDescription":"","lastUpdatedBy":""},
        {"client_Id":"","categoryId":"3","categoryName":"Private Limited Company","categoryDescription":"","lastUpdatedBy":""},
        {"client_Id":"","categoryId":"5","categoryName":"company","categoryDescription":"","lastUpdatedBy":""}
    ]
}
```

so you need to fill the `observableArray` with `result.aaData`:

```
success: function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    self.tableData(result.aaData);
```

### Edit:

Seeing the source of datatbles bindingHandler you're using ([Knockout.js DataTable bindings](http://www.joshbuckley.co.uk/2011/07/knockout-js-datatable-bindings/)), your binding options are incorrect. You should replate `aaData` with `data` here:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" 
    data-bind="
        dataTable: { 
            data: tableData,  // <-- Here!
            options: {
                ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much guys for your prompt response. But I am getting Uncaught object error somewhere in knockoutjs.

Comment: I have change self.tableData() to vm.tableData() but I am getting object is not a function error and Data table alert that table cannot be reinitialize.

Comment: `self.tableData()`is fine, but are using `self.tableData(result.aaData)` as I suggested?

Comment: yes Manji.. I have changed that too. Also, I want to perform inline edit option for the same table. I am referring the below link for the same:http://www.joshbuckley.co.uk/2011/07/knockout-js-datatable-bindings/

Comment: I have tried by removing binding handlers from the link I have mentioned above but cannot reinitialize DataTable warning persists. Also, table is not displaying any data.

Comment: my json data is in the form aaData:... Thats why I have mentioned aaData there. But, I have tried as per your edit but to no avail.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with your code (you can simulate the ajax call with a setTimeout that will populate tableData with static data)? I created [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/cHr2B/2/) feel free to change it to reflect what you have.

Comment: Thanks manji for your efforts but still doesn't work for me. I have updated the jsfiddle. The jsfiddle you have created is exactly same as mine except binding handler function. Object is not a function error and dataTable cannot be reinitialize warning still present.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out! This is what I did to integrate knockout with datatables but I had to add a couple of custom events to knockout's code...

I hope they add the events to knockout source...
**NOTE:  The link for this fiddle does not work**
<strike>[JSFiddle]</strike>

```
 <tbody data-bind="DataTablesForEach: {data: people, options: {jQueryUI:true,scrollY:200,paging:false,scrollCollapse:true, dom: 'rti'}}">
```